# How to have consistent dimensions / theming in tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

On one page in my site, the header bar has: `min-h-8`. On a different page in my site, a different header bar component also has `min-h-8`.

Ideally I'd avoid repeating this value in different places. Otherwise, I might accidentally change the height of one header w/o updating the height of the other header.

What is the recommended Tailwind CSS solution for this?

Comment: The question lacks focus and is slightly opinion based

Comment: Tailwind provides [components](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply) for your needs - it is reusable class (or stack of classes). For example, create `.header` class with `@apply min-h-8;` and use `.header` instead